# Clamper for easy DC-restore in video-composite

Tags: video, diode-clamp

I'm unsure how to properly design a simple clamper in a video circuit like this:

[image: clamper]

The capacitor should be there to avoid any DC offset flowing into the X1 primary loop. I don't know if I can treat the transformer as "transparent" - like it wouldn't be there for the simple one-diode clamper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If input to OPA633 is 2 volts PP, the sync-tip as 40% of the peak-peak voltage will be 0.8 volts and that 1N4148 will function just fine.